# Using JPEG directly from byte array in Android

Tags: android, bitmap, xamarin, jpeg

I am trying to display around 100 JPEG in a list. They are small 77KB files, but if I use `BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray` the files are uncompressed and become 1.6MB. The problem becomes obvious when I then try to load over 100 files ~ 160MB.

I cache the images to persistant storage using BitmapFactory.compress, but I would like to load them as JPEG and use them in that manner as well.

How can I do that?

Currently I am saving/storing the images like this:

```
    public void SaveBitmapAsJpeg (Bitmap bitmap, string imageName)
    {
        lock (Locker) {
            var FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ImageDirectoryPath, imageName);

            using (var Stream = new FileStream (FilePath, FileMode.Create)) 
            {
                const int ImageQuality = 100;
                bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, ImageQuality, Stream);
            }

        }
    }

    /** Returns the file if it exists. Otherwise null. */
    public async Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmap (string imageName)
    {

        var FilePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(ImageDirectoryPath, imageName);

        if (Directory.Exists (ImageDirectoryPath) == true) 
        {
            if (File.Exists(FilePath))
            {
                return await BitmapFactory.DecodeFileAsync (FilePath);
            }
        }

        return null;

    }
```

In order to load the image I check if it is cached and if not, download and cache (save to "disk") the file:

```
/** Returns the cached image file, or if not found downloads and stores the image. */
private async Task<Bitmap> GetCachedImageOrDownloadAndStore (SimplePlaylist playlist) 
    {
        var Bitmap = await ImageStorage.Instance.GetImageBitmap (playlist.Id);
        if (Bitmap != null) 
        {
            return Bitmap;
        }
        else // Cannot find the cached image file
        {
        // download album art
        var Art = await DownloadAlbumArtForPlaylist(playlist);

        // Store the file
        ImageStorage.Instance.SaveBitmapAsPng(Art, playlist.Id);

    return Art;
}
```

The method downloading the JPEG returns a bitmap, because i use BitmapDrawables in order to display them. I am not sure how I can do this any other way.

```
public async static Task<Bitmap> GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;
            byte[] ImageBytes = null;

            var HttpResponseMessage = await AppController.Instance.HttpClient.GetAsync (url);
            await HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCodeAsync();

            ImageBytes = await HttpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync ();

            if (ImageBytes != null && ImageBytes.Length > 0)
            {
                imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(ImageBytes, 0, ImageBytes.Length);
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you use image loading library? Picasso for example?
http://square.github.io/picasso/

Comment: @wilddev Thanks for helpin gout. I was not familiar with it. But also, I am writing the app in Xamarin so I like to keep third party libraries to a minimum.